# Interesting topics of opendata datasets for learning about data warehouses

Tags: data-request, education

I am a final year CS student and have a class about data warehouses.

For term requirements, we are supposed to choose 3 datasets that should have about 10 columns and at least 500 rows each. Otherwise, we are not limited in any way. Then we will process it via data warehouse (i am not exactly sure about details, as I have no experience).
I am from the Czech Republic, but as I said the data origin is not much important.

I have searched multiple sites of opendata providers but could not choose interesting topics that would be related together. I know that there are tons and tons of datasets to choose from, but exactly that is the issue for me that I am overwhelmed with the options and cant choose any.

As I am a total newbie in this field, could you please advise me with topics, you have encountered and found interesting or found some hidden correlation within them?